# How to Handle Unathorized Exception

Tags: exception-handling, authorization

I need to handle unauthorized exception.. My code is something like:

```
try
{
 //MY CODE
}
catch (Exception exx)
{
 //My Code
}
```

I can't understand why if a NOT AUTH exception is thrown, my code didn't pass inside the Exception... UnauthorizedAccessException extends Exception, so WHY this code wont' work?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SharePoint “handles” Access denied exceptions by catching the exception internally and then redirecting the user to a landing page where they can log in to the site. By default this is generally “_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx”.

Since SharePoint redirects the request to the default Access Denied landing page you cannot catch the UnAuthorizedAccessException as the redirect causes a ThreadAbortException to be thrown so your code will never get executed.

In order to handle a thrown `UnAuthorizedAccessException` within your code you first need to set the property `CatchAccessDeniedException` (part of the SPSecurity class) to false. Doing so means that the Access exceptions aren’t handled by the SharePoint platform and the request isn’t redirected.

```
bool orgcatchvalue = SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException;
try{
SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
//your code that may throw an authorization exception
}
catch(UnAuthorizedAccessException)
{
//Code to handle exception
}
finally
{
//set the value back to what it was
SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = orgcatchval;
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to wrap with `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){//The code above})`

Answer (score 2):

You can also wrap your code in a using statement like this

```
using (new SPSecurity.SuppressAccessDeniedRedirectInScope())
    {
        try
        {
            // Code here
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            // code here
        }
    }
```

Doing so will ensure that the SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException boolean is always set back to its previous state and avoid security leaks.